# How to reuse the session in ubuntu using xrdp

Tags: ubuntu, session, xfce, xrdp

I want to use only one session when remote to ubuntu 14.04. I searched in google and found the way, but the setup was not success.

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install xfce4
3. sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
4. sudo apt-get install xrdp
5. Config xsession & startwm.sh file:

echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession

sudo nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
  . /etc/default/locale
  export LANG LANGUAGE
fi

startxfce4
```

5. Config /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini:

   [xrdp8]

   name=test

   lib=libvnc.so

   username=user

   password=pwd

   ip=127.0.0.1

   port=5912
6. sudo service xrdp restart
7. Remote to ubuntu PC, The pop-up shown

   started connecting

   connecting to 127.0.0.1 5912

   error: problem connecting

How can i solve this problem. Please help me. Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver not required to install.

Here I am gonna make use of xfce4 desktop environment.

Follow the steps below:---

1)sudo apt-get update
2)sudo apt-get install xrdp
3)sudo apt-get install xfce4
4)sudo apt-get install xfce4-terminal
5)echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession​
6)nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh


check below script content is there or not in your file (startwm.sh), if not then please add them. 

#!/bin/sh

if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
  . /etc/default/locale
  export LANG LANGUAGE
fi

startxfce4

7) check status whether running or not

   sudo service xrdp status


8) to use same session add below line in mentioned file

go to /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini:

[xrdp8]
name=reconnect
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=ask5910 ( you can also use "port=ask" , but you need to remember previous running 
              port number. )
```

( Note:- default port number is 5910 thats why i have mentioned "port=ask5910".)